# Can't update and use the updated value of window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ when creating universal redux applications

Tags: reactjs, redux

for the past couple of days I have been trying to solve an issue I have with the usage of window.**PRELOADED_STATE** (or whatever name you put to it) when creating an universal applications with ReactJS and Redux. So every time I make a post request to the main page I want the preloaded state to be updated. I have the following **server.js** file:

**server.js**

```js
import express from 'express';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import session from 'express-session';

import configureStore from '../src/js/store';
import routes from '../src/js/routes';
import config from '../webpack.config';

let app=new express();
let compiler=webpack(config);

app.use(session({ secret: 'app' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler));

let renderFullPage=(html, preloadedState) => {
 return `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
   integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <title>Twitter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="app">${html}</div>
   <script>
    window.__USER_INFO__=${JSON.stringify(preloadedState)}
   </script>
   <script src="client.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
 `;
};

app.get(['/', '/login'], (req, res) => {
 let store=configureStore({
  users: {}
 });
 
 if (typeof req.session.info!=='undefined') {
  store=configureStore(req.session.info);
 }

 match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
  if (error) {
   res.status(500).send(error.message);
  } else if (redirectLocation) {
   res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname+redirectLocation.search);
  } else if (renderProps) {
   let html=renderToString(<Provider store={store}>
          <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
         </Provider>);
   let preloadedState=store.getState();
   res.status(200).send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState));
  } else {
   res.status(404).send('Not found');
  }
 });
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
 const { username, password }=req.body;
 req.session.info={
  users: {
   username,
   password
  }
 };
 res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

It should be updating the state, right, but when I try to use the window.**PRELOADED_STATE** inside the **client.js** file (following) it is stuck with the {} which I used to initialize the store with before.

**client.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, hashHistory, match } from 'react-router';

import configureStore from './store';
import routes from './routes';

let preloadedState=window.__USER_INFO__;
let store=configureStore(preloadedState);
const app=document.getElementById('app');

match({ history: hashHistory, routes }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
 ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
      <Router {...renderProps} />
     </Provider>, app);
});
```

Any ideas on how to fix this will be much appreciated. The rest of the code is here: https://github.com/hptks/reactjs-twitter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you logged out your `preloadedState` on the server side?

Comment: What do you mean?